# extracting the complete envelope xml from MessageContext

Tags: soap, spring-ws

I have an interceptor like this:

```
public class WebServiceInterceptor extends EndpointInterceptorAdapter {

@Inject
private Jaxb2Marshaller myJaxb2Marshaller;

@Inject
private WebServiceHistoryDao webServiceHistoryDao;

@Override
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint)
        throws Exception {

    Source payloadSource = messageContext.getRequest().getPayloadSource();
    Object unmarshaled = myJaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(payloadSource);

    //EXTRACT XML HERE
    //is there a better way than this:
    String extractedXml = myJaxb2Marshaller.marshal(unmarshaled);

    return true;
}

}
```

How can i extract the whole xml of envelope (for logging purposes - to write it to the DB)

Comment: I found a solution, and pasted it in the original post (solution by marshaller). Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write one, there's an existing one in the API - `SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor`.  See the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/server/endpoint/interceptor/SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor.html).

> SOAP-specific `EndpointInterceptor` that logs the complete request and response envelope of `SoapMessage` messages. By default, request, response and fault messages are logged, but this behaviour can be changed using the `logRequest`, `logResponse`, `logFault` properties.

If you only need to see the payload, rather than the entire SOAP envelope, then there's `PayloadLoggingInterceptor`.

Comment: I'm using PayloadLoggingInterceptor to see the payload. But what i need is to save it to the Data Base. For that i'm using my own interceptor with a DAO object.

Comment: @Benchik: So subclass one of the above classes, or look at the source code for them to see how they work.